# Ошибки компиляции mongo-php-driver-legacy

Tags: php, linux

На линукс пытаюсь поставить mongo-driver скачал его отсюда -    https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy
скачал , распоковал , перешел в папку с драйвером , выполняю

```
$ phpize  
Configuring for:  
PHP Api Version:         20160303  
Zend Module Api No:      20160303  
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303  

$ ./configure  
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep  
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E  
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed  
checking for cc... cc  
checking whether the C compiler works... yes  
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out  
checking for suffix of executables...   
checking whether we are cross compiling... no  
checking for suffix of object files... o  
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes  
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes  
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed  
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E  
checking for icc... no  
checking for suncc... no  
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes  
checking for system library directory... lib  
checking if compiler supports -R... no  
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes  
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  
checking for PHP prefix... /usr 
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20160303 -I/usr/include/php/20160303/main -I/usr/include/php/20160303/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20160303/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20160303/ext -I/usr/include/php/20160303/ext/date/lib  
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20160303  
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20160303  
checking if debug is enabled... no  
checking if zts is enabled... no  
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.  
checking for gawk... no  
checking for nawk... nawk  
checking if nawk is broken... no  
checking whether to enable Mongo extension... yes, shared  
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no  
checking whether to include code coverage symbols... no  
checking Build with Cyrus SASL support... no  
checking how to print strings... printf  
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed  
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F  
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld  
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes  
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B  
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm  
checking whether ln -s works... yes  
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864  
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop  
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop  
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r  
checking for objdump... objdump  
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all  
checking for dlltool... no  
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n  
checking for ar... ar  
checking for archiver @FILE support... @  
checking for strip... strip  
checking for ranlib... ranlib  
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk  
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok  
checking for sysroot... no  
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd  
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1  
checking for mt... mt  
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no  
checking for ANSI C header files... yes  
checking for sys/types.h... yes    
checking for sys/stat.h... yes   
checking for stdlib.h... yes  
checking for string.h... yes  
checking for memory.h... yes 
checking for strings.h... yes  
checking for inttypes.h... yes  
checking for stdint.h... yes  
checking for unistd.h... yes  
checking for dlfcn.h... yes  
checking for objdir... .libs  
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no  
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC  
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes  
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes  
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes  
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes  
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes  
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no  
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so  
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate  
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes  
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes  
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes   
checking whether to build static libraries... no   
configure: creating ./config.status  
config.status: creating config.h  
config.status: config.h is unchanged  
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

После всего этого пишу команду `make`
и она выдает множество ошибок

```
/bin/bash /opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/libtool --mode=compile cc -I./util -I. -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/include -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/main -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master -I/usr/include/php/20160303 -I/usr/include/php/20160303/main -I/usr/include/php/20160303/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20160303/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20160303/ext -I/usr/include/php/20160303/ext/date/lib -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/api -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/util -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/exceptions -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/gridfs -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/types -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/batch -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/contrib -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/mcon -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/mcon/contrib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.c -o php_mongo.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I./util -I. -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/include -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/main -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master -I/usr/include/php/20160303 -I/usr/include/php/20160303/main -I/usr/include/php/20160303/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20160303/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20160303/ext -I/usr/include/php/20160303/ext/date/lib -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/api -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/util -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/exceptions -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/gridfs -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/types -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/batch -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/contrib -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/mcon -I/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/mcon/contrib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_mongo.o  
In file included from /opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.c:22:0:  
/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.h:197:1: error: unknown type name ‘zend_object_value’  
 zend_object_value php_mongo_type_object_new(zend_class_entry *class_type TSRMLS_DC);  
 ^
/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.h:201:74: error: unknown type name ‘zend_literal’  
 void mongo_write_property(zval *object, zval *member, zval *value, const zend_literal *key TSRMLS_DC);  
                                                                          ^
/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.h:207:71: error: unknown type name ‘zend_literal’  
 zval *mongo_read_property(zval *object, zval *member, int type, const zend_literal *key TSRMLS_DC);  
                                                                       ^
In file included from /opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.c:24:0:  
/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/mongoclient.h:19:1: error: unknown type name ‘zend_object_value’  
 zend_object_value php_mongoclient_new(zend_class_entry *class_type TSRMLS_DC);  
 ^
In file included from /opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/php_mongo.c:43:0:  
/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/types/id.h:19:52: error: unknown type name ‘zend_uint’  
 int php_mongo_id_serialize(zval*, unsigned char**, zend_uint*, zend_serialize_data* TSRMLS_DC);  
                                                    ^
/opt/mongo-php-driver-legacy-master/types/id.h:20:79: error: unknown type name ‘zend_uint’  
 int php_mongo_id_unserialize(zval**, zend_class_entry*, const unsigned char*, zend_uint, zend_unserialize_data* TSRMLS_DC);
```

скопировал не все , их там  оч. много.
Что посоветуете ?

Comment: А версия php какая?

Comment: Читайте документацию по установке, скорее всего вы неправильные версии библиотек использовать пытаетесь

Comment: Стоит 2 версии php 7.1 и 5.6 в зависимости от того какие проекты.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy driver несовместим с PHP7+. Попробуйте собрать под 5.x.

А в чем выражена необходимость использовать именно lagacy-драйвер?

Может быть, вам больше подойдет polifil расширение https://github.com/mongofill или  https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter? Они позволяют работать старым проектам с новым драйвером, даже под php7

Comment: На фирме множество проектов , которые писались еще не мной , и в гайдах по настройке этих проектов указана необходимость поставить legacy - драйвер.

Comment: Legacy driver не заработает с php 7, например. Даже если старый код несовместим с новым драйвером, он заработает с ним через polifil.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось , у меня стояло 2 версии пхп 7.1 и 5.6 , удалив 7.1 получилось поставить legacy-driver.